# What does EventEmitter.call() do?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I saw this code sample:

```
function Dog(name) {
    this.name = name;
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}
```

it 'inherits' from EventEmitter, but what does the call() method actually do?

Comment: Add one note: after declare the function `Dog` this way, still we call:  `util.inherits(Dog, EventEmitter)` to finish inheritance.

Comment: ES6 made life simpler, by `class Dog extends EventEmiter{ //your Dog Class goes here }`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Basically, `Dog` is supposedly a constructor with a property `name`. The `EventEmitter.call(this)`, when executed during `Dog` instance creation, appends properties declared from the `EventEmitter` constructor to `Dog`.

Remember: constructors are still functions, and can still be used as functions.

```
//An example EventEmitter
function EventEmitter(){
  //for example, if EventEmitter had these properties
  //when EventEmitter.call(this) is executed in the Dog constructor
  //it basically passes the new instance of Dog into this function as "this"
  //where here, it appends properties to it
  this.foo = 'foo';
  this.bar = 'bar';
}

//And your constructor Dog
function Dog(name) {
    this.name = name;
    //during instance creation, this line calls the EventEmitter function
    //and passes "this" from this scope, which is your new instance of Dog
    //as "this" in the EventEmitter constructor
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}

//create Dog
var newDog = new Dog('furball');
//the name, from the Dog constructor
newDog.name; //furball
//foo and bar, which were appended to the instance by calling EventEmitter.call(this)
newDog.foo; //foo
newDoc.bar; //bar
```

Comment: Oh, so it is just the constructer of EventEmitter? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @AlexanderCogneau - Construction of the EventEmitter on the current object -- this means the returned Dog is both a Dog and an EventEmitter.

Comment: @Joseph The Dreamer --- Beautiful answer!, explained perfectly.

Comment: Well explained :)

Comment: Thanks! would you mind adding what the goal of the line `events.EventEmitter.call(this)` is likely to be? To me it seems that you would want to append a bunch of the EventEmmitter properties and functions that allow the object to emit it's own events. Is that correct?

Answer (score 30):

```
EventEmitter.call(this);
```

This line is roughly equivalent to calling super() in languages with
classical inheritance.