# What is Event Emitter Call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototypal-inheritance

I am learning Node Js. I have encountered a snippet of code in my book that stated as follow:

```
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var inherits = require('util').inherits;

//Custom class
function Foo(){
   EventEmitter.call(this);
}
inherits(Foo, EventEmitter);

Foo.prototype.connect = function(){
    this.emit('connected');
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.on('connected', function(){
    console.log("connected raised!');
}

foo.connect();
```

My question is that what is "call" here do? Why does the class Foo inherits from EventEmitter? Does that mean that Foo is a child of Event Emitter? If so whu must it be a child of the EventEmitter? I have found another question in Stackoverflow regarding the call ([What does EventEmitter.call() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040717/what-does-eventemitter-call-do)) However, I did not understand the answer provided... Thanks

Source of the code: Beginning Node.js by Basarat Ali Syed

Comment: *"Why does the class Foo inherits from EventEmitter?"* Because the person who created `Foo` wants that every instance of it can trigger events and accept event subscriptions. If it didn't inherit from `EventEmitter`, it would not be possible to call `this.emit` or `foo.on`.

Comment: I guess I'd rather you didn't delete your posts, I went to the trouble of answering it.

Comment: @Dave Newton I have the answer and it was a simple mistake... Sorry

Comment: to understand call function , refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Using_call_to_chain_constructors_for_an_object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line of code:

```
EventEmitter.call(this);
```

calls the constructor of the object you are inheriting from which allows the EventEmitter code to initialize its portion of this object which is part of the inheritance process in Javascript.

`EventEmitter()` is the constructor function for the EventEmitter object.  Since you need to call that constructor with the same `this` as your new object, you must use either `.call()` or `.apply()` with that constructor in order to cause the correct `this` to be used.  Since there are no arguments you are passing to the constructor, `.call()` is the simplest way to call it.

You must call the `EventEmitter()` constructor in order to allow it to properly initialize its portion of the object that was created with `new Foo()`.  When using inheritance in Javascript, multiple separate object definitions are using the same object to store their properties and methods so each much initialize their portion of the object and that initialization is started by calling the constructor of the object that you inherited from.

Here's a good reference on the topic of [chaining constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Example.3A_Using_call_to_chain_constructors_for_an_object).

---

It appears from some of your comments that you don't understand what the point of the inheritance in your code is.  That code allows you to create an object type `Foo` that has your own methods on it, but that object ALSO is an eventEmitter and has all the capabilities of an EventEmitter such that it can trigger events, respond to events, etc...  This is called "inheritance" where you inherit the functionality of some other object with your own custom object.  To make inheritance work, your code does two things.  With the `inherits(Foo, EventEmitter);` line of code, it inherits the prototype of the other object so that it will have all the same methods available and with `EventEmitter.call(this);`, it calls the constructor of the inherited object so that object can initialize itself properly.

You may want to read a couple of reference articles on Javascript inheritance:

[Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

[Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

[Understanding JavaScript Inheritance](https://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance/)

[What is "inheritance" in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027045/what-is-inheritance-in-javascript)

[Inheritance: Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Comment: So does it create a new instance of EventEmitter? So does that mean Foo is another form of EventEmitter?

Comment: @ExtremelySeriousChicken - The new object is already created when you did `new Foo()`.  `EventEmitter.call(this);` lets the EventEmitter constructor initialize its portion of that object.  Remember, this is inheritance so multiple object definitions use the same object and each must initialize their portion of it.

Comment: @ExtremelySeriousChicken: Read the documentation of `call`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: @ExtremelySeriousChicken - it appears that maybe you don't even understand what the inheritance you are using is attempting to do so I've added a paragraph to the end of my answer to describe that.

Comment: @ExtremelySeriousChicken: You might want to read this then: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Answer (score 2):

When applying:

```
inherits(Foo, EventEmitter);
```

`Foo`'s prototype is set to `EventEmitter.prototype`. So, each instance of `Foo` will have all the of `EventEmitter`'s methods (e.g `on`, `emit` etc.)

When Applying:

```
EventEmitter.call(this)
```

within `Foo`'s constructor, it is very similar to calling `new EventEmitter()`, but instead of creating a new context (variable `this`), you are passing your `Foo`'s context.

For example, here is the `EventEmitter`'s constructor [source](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3/blob/master/index.js#L88):

```
function EventEmitter() {
   this._events = new Events();
   this._eventsCount = 0;
}
```

The above class members (`this._events` & `this._eventCount`) are necessary for maintaining the private state of the event emitter.
Applying merely `inherits(Foo, EventEmitter)` will enhance `Foo`'s instances with `EventEmitter`'s methods, however `Foo`'s instances will lack a very basic and crucial initialisation process.

In case a super class has an empty constructor you can skip this step, since it has nothing to assign to `this` variable. Having said that, this is a bad practice since you have no guarantee over this.

Answer (score -2):

It's the ghetto JS way to do inheritance since the language only really supports prototypal inheritance. There is no official language supported class inheritance like in other languages, but the fact that we can run functions against different contexts has become a pretty standard hack for shoehorning in an inheritance hierarchy where an instance of your class can also be considered an instance of its base class. In other words, in `var foo = new Foo()`, `foo` can be said to be both an instance of `Foo` and an `EventEmitter`. In other languages you can setup more explicit inheritance that is supported by the language and compiler.

`.call` is available on all functions and lets you execute the function, but with a different context. `this` in your `Foo` class refers to the instance of `Foo` being created and `EventEmitter.call(this);` is running the `EventEmitter` constructor, but using your instance of `Foo` as the `this` inside the `EventEmitter` constructor. This way, anything that the `EventEmitter` constructor would normally setup on a new instance of pure `EventEmitter` via `var emitter = new EventEmitter();`, will now actually be setup on *your* instance of `Foo`.

Now, this only solves half the goal of achieving JS pseudo-inheritance. If there is anything on the `EventEmitter` prototype that we need to be on our `Foo` prototype, merely calling the `EventEmitter` constructor on your instance of `Foo` is not enough. This is why you also have to call `util.inherits(Foo, EventEmitter);`.

`util.inherits` just sets the prototype of `Foo` to a new object that inherits from the prototype of `EventEmitter`. It also adds the `EventEmitter` constructor as a `.super_` property to your `Foo` constructor which I believe is a Java convention to make it easy to access the base constructor (the constructor of the class you inherit from). https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L634-L644